# default template arguments in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Suppose i have a function template StrCompare

```
template<typename T=NonCaseSenCompare>//NonCaseSenCompare is a user defined class look at the detailed code below.
int StrCompare(char* str1, char* str2)
{
...
}
```

now in the main function i write a line

```
char* str1="Zia";
char* str2="zia";
int result=StrCompare(str1,str2);
```

it should work because we have provided a default template argument, but it does'nt 
compiler gives the following error
no matching function for call to `StrCompare(char*&, char*&)' 
Now the detailed code is given by

```
#include<iostream.h>
class CaseSenCompare
{
public: 
static int isEqual(char x, char y)
{
return x==y;
}
};
class NonCaseSenCompare
{
public:
static int isEqual(char x,char y)
{
char char1=toupper(x);
char char2=toupper(y);
return char1==char2;
}
};
template<typename T=NonCaseSenCompare>
int StrCompare(char* str1, char* str2)
{
for(int i=0;i < strlen(str1)&& strlen(str2);i++)
{
if(!T::isEqual(str1[i],str2[i]))
return str1[i]-str2[i];
}
return strlen(str1)-strlen(str2);
}

main()
{
char* ptr1="Zia ur Rahman";
char* ptr2="zia ur Rahman";
int result=StrCompare(ptr1,ptr2);//compiler gives error on this line
cout<<result<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

If I write

```
int result=StrCompare<>(ptr1,ptr2);
```

compiler gives the same error message.

Comment: I don't think we will ever get rid of the "Hay Dear!" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [gf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328408/2328461#2328461) and [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328408/2328485#2328485) already wrote, you can't have default template arguments with function templates. However, if you turn your comparators  into function objects, you can still use default function arguments:

```
template<typename Comp>
int StrCompare(char* str1, char* str2, Comp = NonCaseSenCompare())
{
  ...
}
```

You can now call `StrCompare()` like this

```
StrCompare("abc","aBc",CaseSenCompare());
```

or like this:

```
StrCompare("abc","aBc"); // uses NonCaseSenCompare
```

A comparator would then have to look like this:

```
struct CaseSenCompare {
  bool operator()(char x, char y) const {return x==y;}
};
```

Adjust `StrCompare()` accordingly.

Comment: yes, i have got the point we can not give default template arguments incase of function templates. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

*§14.1/9*:

> A default template-argument shall not
>   be specified in a function template
>   declaration or a function template
>   definition, nor in the
>   template-parameter-list of the
>   definition of a member of a class
>   template.

A simple work-around would be to move it into a class:

```
template<typename T=NonCaseSenCompare>
struct StrCompare {
    static int compare(char* str1, char* str2) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: thought so, wasn't sure though.

Comment: then where we specify default template argument

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, function templates do not support default template arguments, only class templates do.

Secondly, even when all *class* template parameters have default arguments, you still have to specify an empty `<>` to refer to that class template.

Comment: Is it mean that we can not give default template arguments in case of function templates , we can only give default template arguments in case of class member functions?

Comment: i have got the point, yes you are right we can not give default template arguments in case of function templates

Answer (score 0):

What i use is next trick;

lets say you want to have function like this

```
template <typename E, typename ARR_E = MyArray_t<E> > void doStuff(ARR_E array)
{
    E one(1);
    array.add( one );
}
```

you will not be allowed, but i do next way:

```
template <typename E, typename ARR_E = MyArray_t<E> >
class worker {
public:
    /*static - as you wish */ ARR_E* parr_;
    void doStuff(); /* do not make this one static also, MSVC complains */
};

template <typename E, typename ARR_E>
void worker::doStuff<E, ARR_E>::getChunks()
{
    E one(1);
    parr_->add( one );
}
```

so this way you may use it like this.

```
MyArray_t my_array;
worker<int> w;
w.parr_ = &arr;
w.doStuff();
```

as we can see no need to explicitly set second parameter.
maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.